# How to instanciate a guava Table dynamically?

Tags: java, guava

I'm stuck with the follwoing problem:
I want to use guava tables as they provide a convenient transpose operation. In Java 8 a guava table can be instanciated like this:

```
Table<R,C,V> table = HashBasedTable.createTable();
```

All examples I found use static instanciation concerning the types and the number of columns. Unfortunately, I do not know the number of columns at design time, so I have to find a way to instanciate the Table with arguemtns which I have to determine at run time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it out myself, I misunderstood the documentation:

First I thought, a guava Table is instanciated like:

```
Table<T,....,T> table = HashBasedTable.createTable();
```

With N type definitions for each column.

But Reading the documentation more carefully, I found out that the instanciation
is done by

```
Table<R, C, V> table = HashBasedTable.createTable();
```

Where R is the type of the row key, C type column key, V value type. Hence one can for instance instanciate a matrix of Double values via:

```
Table<Integer, Integer, Double> matrix = HashBasedTable.createTable();
```

and access the matix via the cell indices (Integer, Integer).

Comment: I was going crazy trying to understand what you actually mean in the question... this is sooo much simpler